# smarty - error in assign

Tags: php, smarty

I use assign like this :

```
$smarty->assign("akakak", $_POST[do]);
```

it's work in some cases but it isn't work in some cases

when I add this parameter

```
$smarty->assign("akakak", $_POST[do], true);
```

it's always work

Why ?

Comment: Are you checking first if `if isset($_POST['do'])` before assigning?  Place quotes around `do`, since you're forcing PHP to interpret a constant as a string array key.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL)` is your friend... you should use `$_POST['do']` not `$_POST[do]`

Answer (score 2):

You should check or set a default value:

```
<?php 
//Check it or set default for $do
$do=(isset($_POST['do']))?$_POST['do']:'';

//Assign the $smarty var with $do
$smarty->assign("akakak", $do);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assigning the values of superglobals ($_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST, $_SESSION, $_COOKIE, $_SERVER, $_ENV) is redundant. You can access any of these within a template through the [{$smarty}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl#language.variables.smarty.request) variable, in your case `{$smarty.post.do}`.

The following is true for Smarty3:

The third argument to [assign()](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.assign.tpl) is the nocache flag. For more information on this, see [cacheability of variables](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/caching.cacheable.tpl#cacheability.variables). If this actually solved your problem, your real problem lies with your caching. You likely have `$smarty->caching = true;` set, in which case the template is not rendered on every invocation, but read from cache if possible.

If you need further assistance, you may want to elaborate on the failing cases.

Aside from that, please have a close look at the other comments suggesting `$_POST['do']` over `$_POST[do]` and the use of `isset()` or `empty()` where applicable.